# Modifying PHP superglobals other than $_ENV

Tags: php

In PHP I want to be able to set a variable value "superglobally" - that is a *me-defined* value that is accessible to EVERY script that runs on the server at its FIRST line of code (i.e. without having to require_once() anything or anything like that).

Currently I'm using **$_ENV[ 'varname' ]** by setting an environment variable on my system called **varname**.  But it requires a reboot to make a change to the variable value on a Windows system, which is not good.

Are there any other solutions short of modifying php source?

Comment: Care to share *why* you're doing this?

Comment: @hobodave > To know for sure on which environment the application is currently running, to know wich configuration file should be loaded, for instance (without having some kind of if based on the server's name, or the IP address, or stuff like that) ; it's not the first time I hear about this idea, and I kinda like it (even if I've never used it myself yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a value in your `php.ini` which you can then retrieve with [`get_cfg_var`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Apache, you could take a look at [`mod_env`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html)

It will allow you to use the `SetEnv` directive in Apache's configuration *(and in .htaccess files, if your Apache server is configured so you can use those)*, like this :

In my Apache's file :

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName      tests
        DocumentRoot /home/squale/developpement/tests

        ....

        SetEnv MY_TEST_VARIABLE "Hello, World!"

        ....

</VirtualHost>
```

*(Require's an Apache restart to be taken into account)*

Or in an .htaccess file :

```
SetEnv MY_OTHER_TEST_VARIABLE "This is looking nice !"
```

*(Immediatly taken into account)*

And, then, these variables are available in `$_SERVER` :

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

Gives me :

```
array
  'MY_TEST_VARIABLE' => string 'Hello, World!' (length=13)
  'MY_OTHER_TEST_VARIABLE' => string 'This is looking nice !' (length=22)
  'HTTP_HOST' => string 'tests' (length=5)
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090716 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Shiretoko/3.5.1' (length=105)
  'HTTP_ACCEPT' => string 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' (length=63)
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => string 'en-us,en;q=0.5' (length=14)
  ....
  ....
```

It's not `$_ENV` like you requested... But almost ;-)

And the idea is really the same ^^

Answer (score 4):

You can use the php.ini setting [`auto_prepend_file`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) for this task. It allows you to specify an PHP script that is run just before any 'normal' PHP script is executed.

To quote the manual:

> `auto_prepend_file  string`
>
> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require() function, so include_path is used.
>
> The special value none disables auto-prepending.

To make a variable a super-global there, just extend one of the other super-globals, like you did with $_ENV, e.g.,

```
<?php
$_ENV['mystuff'] = "Hello World!";
$_SERVER['FOO'] = "BAR";
?>
```

Cheers,